# Start for-loop at 0 (instead of 1)

Tags: excel, vba

Why am I not able to start for-loops at 0?

```
Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 1 To 10
    Cells(0, counter).Value = arr(counter)
Next counter
```

This will miss the first index in the array.

Is there any possible solution to this issue?

Comment: The first column is column `1` and not column `0`. Try it yourself and put into cell `A1` the following formula: `=column()`. There is no column `0`.

Comment: More generally, cells, columns, rows and most other things in Office apps are members of Collections. While arrays can be 0- or 1-based, Collections are always 1-based.

Comment: Cells(1, counter) etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an alternative to what @Ralph points out, you can use `Offset` of the `Range` - thus both -- your array and range reference will be starting at 0:

```
Dim counter As Integer
For counter = 0 To 9
    Cells(1, 1).Offset(0, counter).Value = arr(counter)
Next counter
```

P.S.: Avoid naming your array `array` as there is a VBA function with the same name. You can go with something like `arr` instead.

Comment: but why use offset when 1 can just be subtracted from the array arg?

Comment: @SteveMartin Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @StevenMartin - that is why I started with "as an alternative" :-). I'd also say that code looks cleaner when you don't have to adjust indices, but it is a matter of taste and conventions you decided to follow in your code. Functionally it is the same.

Comment: Functionally it is not the same until you change 10 to 9

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[Option Base 1](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266179.aspx)** but it has limited control over what and how arrays get indexed.

The [Split function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263365(v=vs.60).aspx) always creates a zero-based single dimension array regardless of whether you have changed the default to `Option Base 1` or not.

Bulk loading worksheet [.Value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) into a variant array always produces a 1-based two dimensioned array regardless of whether you explicitly set `Optiona Base 0` or only reference a single row or single column of cells.

I find it best to always use the [LBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9a7w1ac.aspx) and [UBound](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278658.aspx) functions to get the extents of an array. Adjust the numbers so you are not trying to reference cell A0 or something similar (e.g. `#REF!` ).

```
Dim counter As Long
debug.print Lbound(arr) & ":" & uBound(arr)
For counter = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    Cells(1, counter + 1).Value = arr(counter)
Next counter
```

Comment: So does the `Option Base` affect anything besides `Dim`ing of arrays using only the upper bound?

Comment: `Option Base 1` will convert `dim arr(9)` as `dim arr(1 to 9)` (9 array elements). The default (`Option Base 0`) would create `dim arr(9)` as `dim arr(0 to 9)` (total of 10 elements). I tend not to use `Option Base xx` at all and either force lower and upper boundaries with `dim arr(1 to 9)` or accept `dim arr(9)` and mentally keep track of the zero-based and one-based arrays.

Answer (score 0):

simple....

```
Dim counter As Integer

For counter = 1 To 10
    Cells(1, counter).Value = array(counter - 1)
Next counter
```